# Difference between Empty and None in Service messages

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a client for the service /static_map. The static_map service uses the service message of type empty request and some response type.(by empty request,I mean no data type was mentioned in request)
In the client that I created:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from nav_msgs.srv import GetMap,GetMapRequest
rospy.init_node("my_caller")
rospy.wait_for_service("/static_map")
my_connector=rospy.ServiceProxy("/static_map",GetMap)
my_call=GetMapRequest()
result=my_connector(my_call)
print(result)
```

The above code works perfectly but when I replace the line my_call=GetMapRequest() to my_call=Empty(), I get an error. So is empty data type not equal to the blank data type of the service request?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342218/difference-between-empty-and-none-in-service-messages/) by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the service definition of the service your are referring to (from [nav_msgs/GetMap](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetMap.html)):

```
# Get the map as a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid
---
nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid map
```

The part that gets transformed in the `GetMapRequest` type (the one you `import` from `nav_msgs.srv`) contains the fields in the upper part of the message definition (ie: above the `---`).

The response would be the lower part (ie: below the `---`).

The request part does indeed not contain any fields, just a single comment. So the request type is "empty", but only in the sense it does not contain any additional fields.

This is *not* the same as the `std_msgs/Empty`. This is an entirely different message type. It is called `Empty`, as it does not have any fields (from [std_msgs/Empty](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Empty.html)):

Even though it does not contain any fields, this is a different message type, and it is not used for the request type of the `GetMap` service.

> when I replace the line `my_call=GetMapRequest()` to `my_call=Empty()`, I get an error.

Yes. This is expected, as they are not the same types (`GetMapRequest` is the request type).

> So is empty data type not equal to the blank data type of the service request?

Exactly.

But do note: "blank data type of the [`GetMap`] service request" is not a type. That would be `GetMapRequest`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on 2020-01-24**:
Thanks for your reply but I didn't use `std_srvs/Empty`, rather I used `std_msgs/Empty` which is not a service but a data type.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-24**:
That would not change my answer much. The underlying cause is that an empty service `*Request` is not the same type as any other message or service (so neither `std_msgs/Empty` nor `std_srvs/EmptyRequest` is the same type).

It's just how the typing system for topics and services (and actions) works.

**Comment by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on 2020-01-24**:
Thanks a lot for ur help!!